# Two text rows in trailing flutter ListTile

Tags: flutter, listtile

I am trying to display two text rows in the trailing property of ListTile
How can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ListTile(
      title: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text('Test'),
          const Text('pagago por: Carlo'),
        ],
      ),
      trailing: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          const Text('\$ 210,00'),
          const Text('12/6/22 23:14'),
        ],
      ),
      dense: false,
    ),
```